# Querying Hive via Pyspark return empty result

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I run spark 2.1.0 on top of AWS EMR cluster (based on the following -https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyterhub-on-amazon-emr/)

I try to query a table which exists and have data inside in a remote HIVE. Spark interfere the schema correctly but the table content is empty. Any idea?

```
import os
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/lib/spark/')

# Spark related imports
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sc.getConf()).getOrCreate()

remote_hive = "jdbc:hive2://myhost:10000/mydb"
driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
user="user"
password = "password"

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").\
    options(url=remote_hive, 
            driver=driver, 
            user=user, 
            password=password, 
            dbtable="mytable").load()


df.printSchema()
# returns the right schema
df.count()
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try -

```
spark\
  .read.format("jdbc")\
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("url", remote_url)
  .option("dbtable", "mytable")
  .option("user", "user")\
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

Comment: Same result - empty table (df.count() = 0)